# What is your funny meme about programming?

Tags: linux, windows, unix, tags, computer-science

Take a break and post your funny meme related to programming

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here I got one
[image]
[image]

More you can find on [turnoff.us](http://turnoff.us/)